# "0 сообщения" вместо "0 сообщений"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Собственно вот, на странице проверок. "0 сообщени**й**" надо бы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В англоязычной версии «0 posts». Возможно из-за этого и нет форм слова для перевода. Однако, на Transifex есть несколько форм «posts», которые все были «сообщения». Поправил. Если до завтра нужная строка будет не на месте, то будет необходимо новые формы добавить.